# tableview edit mode cell selection checkmark disappearing on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with editing mode enabled so that I can select multiple cells for delete.  When I select a cell, the blue check mark appears on the LEFT side of the cell.  However, when I scroll the selected cells out of view, then scroll back to the selected cells, I see that the check mark disappears.  I can see the cell is still selected since the selectedBackgroundView color is different than the none selected cells, but the checkmark keeps disappearing.

I enter editing mode by doing `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];`

I keep an array of the selected cells `NSArray *selectedRows = [self.audioTable indexPathsForSelectedRows];`

The selected cell:

[image: Cell selected]

After scrolling the selected cell out of view then returning back to the selected cell, the checkmark disappears, but the cell is still in the selected state:

[image: When scrolled out of view then back into view the checkmark disappears]

I know I need to implement something like the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but I don't know how to get the checkmark back

```
NSArray *selectedRows = [self.audioTable indexPathsForSelectedRows];
for (NSIndexPath *selectionIndex in selectedRows)
{
    if(selectionIndex.row == indexPath.row)
    {
        cell.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

I did try setting the `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` but the cell still comes back unselected.  According to the documentation the check mark located on the left has to do with editing controls and the checkmark on the right has to do with `accessoryView`, so I'm not sure if this question is a dupe of the others...

Comment: Also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395306/check-marks-are-unchecked-when-scroll-the-tableview?rq=1

Comment: You need to set `cell.accessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

Comment: I tried setting the `cell.accessoryType` but no luck.  Also, isn't `accessoryType` for the `accessoryView` which is on the right side of the cell?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake

Comment: @rmaddy the other questions you're referring to are all related to the `accessoryType.  I believe when selecting cells when the tableview is in editing mode is different...

Comment: You said the checkmark disappears. What checkmark do you mean if you aren't talking about the accessoryType?

Comment: @rmaddy I thought the accessory checkmark is on the right like this: <http://i.stack.imgur.com/bmIG3.png>  I'm talking about the checkmarks on the left when the tableview is in edit mode: <http://s3.amazonaws.com/cocoacontrols_production/ios_screens/1195/full.png?1345655136>

Comment: I reopened the question but you need to provide more details in your question. Show more code related to how you setup your cells and how you add the checkmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, which leads to another problem.  Prior to hitting this issue, my separator line was always disappearing every time i selected a cell and none of the SO solutions worked for me.  I noticed that the separator line was disappearing when my selectionStyle was anything other than `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.  In order to keep the separator line from disappearing but also keep the blue checkmarks, I set my selectionStyle to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  However, when my tableview went into editing mode, I would switch my selectionStyle to 'UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue' and switch it back to 'UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone' when coming out of edit mode.  This worked perfectly...until now.

So whenever I entered editing mode, I called a custom method in my tableViewCell class that did the following:

```
-(void) changeSelectionStyle: (BOOL) inDefaultMode
{
    if(inDefaultMode)
    {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }
    else
    {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

}
```

So as of now, whenever I scroll the cells out of the view then scroll back to the selected cells, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is setting the selection style to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you checkmarks are disappearing is because iOS recycles cells. I would bet there's a chance you could see cells you didn't select start to show up with checkmarks if you have some cells selected and start scrolling enough. Basically, your cell disappears from the screen and then you scroll back to it. iOS grabs a recycled cell that happened to have the checkmark hidden the last time it was used.

So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should explicitly set the checkmark visible or hidden based on whether or not the cell is selected so that when the cell is reused for a new item, it is correctly hiding or showing the checkmark.